# im looking design pattern for developed project in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

its an java mysql application i put connection string in Connect.java and call it from Registration.java, which design pattern is that??

Connect.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Connect {
     Connection con=null;

        public static Connection ConnectDB(){
             try{

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms_db","root","1474514745");
          return con;

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
    }      
}
}
```

Registration.java

```
con=Connect.ConnectDB();
   con=Connect.ConnectDB();
            Statement stmt;
       stmt= con.createStatement();
       String sql1="Select PatientID from PatientRegistration where PatientID= '" + txtPatientID.getText() + "'";
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
      if(rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Patient ID already exists","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtPatientID.setText("");
        txtPatientID.requestDefaultFocus();
       return;
      }
            String sql= "";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successfully Registered","Patient",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            btnSave.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Command Pattern**

That is the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). The idea behind this pattern is to allow functionality to be passed around. A typical Command class contains a simple method, execute. For example:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

public class MyCommand implements Command { 
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("This is the output from MyCommand");
    }
}
```

This is useful when you aren't sure what functionality will be needed at run time, so you create a pool of commands and select them as needed, usually by some external configuration.

Another motivation for this pattern is that it allows you to chain your commands together in a dynamic data structure, allowing you to implement "undo" functionality very easily. Obviously this would create the need for a `revert()` method in our example.

**Factory Pattern**

It is also the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This pattern allows you to abstract the details of an objects creation away from the classes that call it. In your case, you don't want internal knowledge of your Database connection details to be littered all over your app, so you wrap it up in the Factory method so that it simply churns out a connection object when you want it.

**Note**

- You have an SQL Injection vulnerability in your code. This will allow users to insert their own SQL and run unauthorised queries on your database.
- Doing it this way introduces a concept called "Global State" into your application. This is generally undesirable. Instead, I would recommend using a Dependency Injection framework to inject this object into your classes. That way, no code needs knowledge of your DB details; it's all stored in a config file.

Comment: i have an netbeans project called hospital management system, can you help me to find out design patterns. Source code link: http://www.sourcecodester.com/sites/default/files/download/RajLovesAshi/hospital_management_system_0.zip

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not. I only really answers questions on here and I don't tend to give one to one support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `Thread safe Singleton`, it's the best way to have DB connection and handle your SQL's